# Problem with a dropdown list as an UpdatePanel's trigger

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown list in my user control. It's behavior is strange: SelectedIndexChanged event handler is not called when the item with attribute Selected="True" is selected. I.e. when the page loads, everything is fine. Then I select some other dropdown list element, and it works fine, too. But when I after that go back to the item selected by default, the event handler is not executed. This dropdown list is used as a trigger for an updatepanel. If I remove it from being a trigger, it works fine. But I need it to update that UpdatePanel. How could it be fixed?

Thanks.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilter" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                    Height="20px" Width="200px" 
                                    CausesValidation="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlFilter_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="-2" Selected="True" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="My Titles" Value="-1" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Cancelled Titles" Value="0" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="On Offer" Value="1" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="For Consideration" Value="2" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Make Offer" Value="3" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="On Hold" Value="4" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Researching" Value="5" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Titles from Existing Authors" Value="6" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

In code behind:

```
protected void ddlFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

...
}

Comment: You should add your UpdatePanels' aspx-markup.

Comment: where is the markup for your update panel? can we see it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the structure of your page so I don't know why setting it as trigger does not work but you can call

```
UpdatePanel1.Update()
```

manually from `ddlFilter_SelectedIndexChanged` to refresh the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, I tried it, but it didn't change anything. ddlFilter_SelectedIndexChanged() is just not executed when the initial element is selected.